# How could I see the content of the Predefined variable in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example:

```
{
        "name": "MinGW",
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
        "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17"
}
```

I want to know what `${workspaceFolder}` exactly is in this situation.
Is there a way to print it's content in the terminal or in a file?

Comment: I think you might have to make and run a task like  {
      "label": "echo workspaceRoot",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "echo ${workspaceRoot}"
    }, to see it print the value in a console.

Comment: @Mark Okay, i will try it.Thanks.